# Como importar Javascript no angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Saudação para todos,

Eu sei importar os arquivos css para dentro de um projeto feito com a nova versão do Angular como pode ver abaixo:

Arquivos **angular-cli.json**

```
 "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/ng2-toasty/style-bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

Porém minha dificuldade agora é importar arquivos JavaScript, não sei como faço!, eu tentei colocar o caminho do JavaScript nessa mesma linha de código acima e não deu certo, e ai analisar melhor esse arquivo **angular-cli.json**  encontrei esse trecho de código

```
"e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
```

Esse arquivo está na raiz do projeto, ele se encontra assim:

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

Não sei se entenderam minha dúvida, mas resumidamente preciso conectar um arquivo JavaScript para pode criar implementações de javascript no projeto angular, é isso!

[Para quem quiser dá uma olhada no meu projeto está aqui:](https://github.com/wladyband/controle-de-cervejas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare os scripts dentro do arquivo angular-cli.json.

```
"scripts": [
    "../path" 
 ];
```

Então adicione no typings.d.ts

```
declare var nomeVariavel:any;
```

No seu arquivo, importe da seguinte maneira:

```
import * as variable from 'nomeVariavel';
```

Interessante reiniciar o ng server após feito isso, caso ele já esteja rodando.